# How to give a Smartsheet access to someone with API?

Tags: smartsheet-api

With PHP, I create a smartsheet from excel file with **smartsheet API**. Everything is working fine so far. But I also want to give **right access** to the new smartsheet to a **specific user** to allow him to open it from a browser.

The user already has a smartsheet account.

Is there a smartsheet endpoint that allows this to be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation you're looking for is [Share Sheet](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#share-sheet).

The following example request grants the Smartsheet user who's registered with email address `jane.doe@test.com` **EDITOR** (write) access to the sheet that's specified by `sheetId` in the request URL.

```
POST /sheets/{sheetId}/shares
[
  {
    "email": "jane.doe@test.com", 
    "accessLevel": "EDITOR"
  }
]
```

A couple of notes:

- By default, the **Share Sheet** operation won't send an email to the user to notify them that they've been granted access to the sheet. If you want it to send them an email, you'll need to specify the query string parameter/value `sendEmail=true` on the request URL, and specify the `message` and `subject` properties in the body of the request. See [Share Sheet](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#share-sheet) in the API docs for details about this.
- If you want the user to be able to share the sheet with others, you'll want to specify **EDITOR_SHARE** as the access level (instead of **EDITOR**). See [Access Levels](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#access-levels) in the API docs for details about the various permissions.

Comment: Thank you. It's working fine :D